# Travis CI error while devtools::chech() doesn't

Tags: r, yaml, travis-ci, devtools

[Here is the package in github](https://github.com/cesarkero/MasteringSofwareDevelopmentInRCapstone).

As you can see in travis.yml, warnings are not treated as errors. When I do the `check()` in console, there are no errors. Here is the result:

```
0 errors ✓ | 4 warnings x | 1 note x
```

And here are the last lines of Travis CI.

```
ERROR: dependency ‘raster’ is not available for package ‘leaflet’
* removing ‘/home/travis/R/Library/leaflet’
* installing *source* package ‘modelr’ ...
** package ‘modelr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (modelr)
* installing *source* package ‘tidyverse’ ...
** package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (tidyverse)
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpX59PJA/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status
2: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
3: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status
4: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
5: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘leaflet’ had non-zero exit status
missing: terra, raster, units, leaflet, sf
The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

What should I modify to get the it pass through Travis CI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seem that your package depends, at least, on `raster` and `sf`; and your script does not install them:

```
1: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status
2: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
3: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status
4: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
```

The reason is most likely that you do not install the required system dependencies (GDAL, GEOS, ...). You need to add something like this to your system before installing these packages

`sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev libgeos-dev libudunits2-dev netcdf-bin`

I think that in a travis file that goes like this

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libgdal-dev
      - libproj-dev
      - libudunits2-dev
      - netcdf-bin
```

You may prefer using github actions. See e.g. this [workflow](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/.github/workflows/rcmdcheck.yml) for `terra`

Comment: Do you mean adding these lines to .travis.yml ? -->
install:
    sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev libgeos-dev libudunits2-dev netcdf-bi

Comment: Yes, but then in the equivalent for travis. I have added what I believe it is to the question.

Comment: I added this line to the travis.yml based on your solution and it worked --> `before_install: sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev libgeos-dev libudunits2-dev netcdf-bin`